# Return the result of swapping the two lower-order bytes of X

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Problem and solution:

```
/** Return the result of swapping the two lower-order bytes of X.
* For example, if X is 0x12345678, then swap(X) is 0x12347856. */
static int swapLower(int X) {
    /* Solution */
    int lower = X & 0x0000ffff;
    int upper = X & 0xffff0000;

    return upper | (0xffff & ((lower << 8) | (lower >> 8)));
}
```

I am confused about how to understand the solution. I tried working through the logic but I did not understand.

Also, I don't know how to come up with the solution in the first place!

EDIT:

**Properties:**

```
x & 1 = x
x & 0 = 0
x | 1 = 1
x | 0 = x
```

1. **int lower = X & 0x0000ffff** = X & 0b00000000000000001111111111111111 = 0b0000000000000000x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>0</sub>
2. **int upper = X & 0xffff0000** = X & 0b11111111111111110000000000000000 = 0bx<sub>31</sub> ... x<sub>16</sub>0000000000000000
3. **lower << 8** = 0b0000000000000000x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>0</sub> << 8 = 0b00000000x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>0</sub>00000000
4. **lower >> 8** = 0b0000000000000000x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>0</sub> >> 8 = 0bssssssss00000000x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>8</sub>

   - **(assuming `X` is a signed number, then `s` is the sign bit; it's 0 if `X` is positive and 1 if `X` is negative)**
5. **(lower << 8) | (lower >> 8)** = 0b00000000x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>0</sub>00000000 | 0bssssssss00000000x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>8</sub> = 0bssssssssx<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>0</sub>x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>8</sub>
6. **0xffff & ((lower << 8) | (lower >> 8))** = 0b000000000000000001111111111111111 & 0bssssssssx<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>0</sub>x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>8</sub> = 0b00000000000000000x<sub>7</sub> ... x<sub>0</sub>x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>8</sub>
7. **upper | (0xffff & ((lower << 8) | (lower >> 8)))** = 0bx<sub>31</sub> ... x<sub>16</sub>0000000000000000 | 0b00000000000000000x<sub>7</sub> ... x<sub>0</sub>x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>8</sub> = x<sub>31</sub> ... x<sub>16</sub>x<sub>7</sub> ... x<sub>0</sub>x<sub>15</sub> ... x<sub>8</sub>

Comment: Are you saying this is the solution and you don't understand it

Comment: I'm saying it's the given solution and that (1) I don't understand it and (2) I don't know how to derive it in the first place. please help me!

Comment: The edit looks right except the bit about the sign bit is a red herring because step 1 already cleared the sign bit so it is ALWAYS zero in steps 2-6.  And in the end (Step 7) the sign bit gets set back to x31 just like it was in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  That's harder to understand than necessary.

I think this is easier to understand:

```
int lowest2     = (X & 0x000000FF) << 8; // lowest byte moved 8 bits left
int nextLowest2 = (X & 0x0000FF00) >> 8; // next lowest byte move 8 bits right
int upper4      = (X & 0xFFFF0000);
return upper4 | lowest2 | nextLowest2;
```

Then when X = 0x12345678:

```
upper4 | lowest2 | nextLowest2 = 0x12340000 | 0x00007800 | 0x00000056;
```

But of course if you analyse the solution you gave you get the same thing:

If upper and lower are defined as:

```
int lower = X & 0x0000FFFF
int upper = X & 0xffff0000;
```

Then:

```
X                                                = 0x12345678
lower                                            = 0x00005678
(lower << 8)                                     = 0x00567800
(lower >> 8)                                     = 0x00000056
((lower << 8) | (lower >> 8))                    = 0x00567856
(0xFFFF & ((lower << 8) | (lower >> 8)))         = 0x00007856
upper                                            = 0x12340000
upper | (0xffff & ((lower << 8) | (lower >> 8))) = 0x12345678
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry, thats a very good explanation! :) can u check my work that i just did? what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The given solution is correct, but overly complicated and thus more difficult to understand than necessary. The following solution is much easier to comprehend:

```
return X & 0xffff0000 | ((X & 0xff00) >> 8) | ((X & 0xff) << 8);
```

It simply pulls three parts out of the number and rearranges them. To understand it, think about each `|`-separated component, considering what part of the number it selects and where that part ends up in the result.

Comment: can u explain each component? i'm having trouble!

Comment: You have to do at least some of the thinking yourself. A good way to figure it out is to run various different numbers, expressed in hexadecimal notation, through it, print out each part of the expression separately and try to understand what's happening to them. Try 0x12, 0x2300, 0x2345 and 0x12345678.

Comment: @MarceloCantos I understand where you're coming from, but if he's asking for help with his solution, and you propose another solution and tell him to try it out, what are the odds that he's going to understand?  Perhaps giving a simpler solution and pointing him to good reference would suffice, but this doesn't IMO.

Comment: @SteveP.: The most important thing is that the penny has to drop regarding what role masking and bit-shifting play. I've given the OP an answer in which it is easy to discern how these elements work together. Once he gets his head around it, he should be able to go back to the original solution and make sense of it. Trying to explain the original solution without first grounding the OP in these basic elements will leave them hopelessly confused. This may be a bit round-about, but I don't believe in spoonfeeding. If you disagree, then feel free to post another solution.

Comment: i'm so sad... i'm hopeless confused already because you're proposing this solution and not explaining.....

Comment: @FrankEpps While I don't necessarily agree with Marcelo's tough love, you really do need to put effort into this.  There are countless resources that explain bit-shifting/bitwise operations.  They may not contain this exact problem, but studying them will help you.

Comment: @FrankEpps: Rather than being sad, just type up the solution I proposed, including printing out the different parts (e.g., `printf("%x %x %x …\n", X & 0xffff0000, X & 0xff00, ((X & 0xff00) >> 8, …)`) and run different numbers (supplied using 0x… notation) through it and see what comes out.

Comment: @Steve P, i have poured through all the resources about bit operations and I understand each one. The problem is I don't comprehend how to devise such an intricate solution!

Comment: @Marcelo i know your answer is correct based on tests in Java, but I don't know how you came up with that! i'm starting to think you're here just to flaunt ur knowledge and not explain urself properly....

Comment: @FrankEpps Well then, you need to edit your question with more details about exactly what you're confused about.  Ostensibly, it looks like you have no idea what's going on.  If you read a lot, and actually understood it, you should have more to show.  PS: I'm done commenting, especially since it looks like you are trolling or giving a poor attempt at reverse psychology.  Good luck.

Comment: @FrankEpps: A bit of experimentation like what I suggested, and it will start to click, and it will be so obvious how it's put together that you won't need to ask how to come up with such solutions.

Comment: @FrankEpps Don't have time to answer, but after a cursory look Jerry's answer, it seems to be good/well explained.

Comment: @Steve P, i'm shocked that u'd call me a troll. i'm trying to learn and Marcelo just flaunts his knowledge and refuses to explain, then u show up and say i'm trolling. i was able to prove that the original solution was correct, but i still don't know how to derive it. i'm still laboring through Jerry's explanation. i'd appreciate it if u redact ur hurtful comment

Comment: @FrankEpps: I also wondered if you were trolling. You demonstrated barely any grasp of some fairly basic concepts, and when I explained to you how you could figure this stuff out yourself (which is far better than being spoon-fed, as evidenced by your ongoing struggle with JerryJeremiah's very detailed explanation), instead of going off and trying my suggestions, you complained about being sad that no one would help you. No one used bad language or made threats, so get yourself a thicker skin. And stop whining about *free* advice that doesn't fit your expectations.

Comment: marcelo if ur going to offer an answer, you should make it helpful. urs was hardly. why do u persist in mocking me for my cluelessness in this topic area? i just started learning about bits last night!

Comment: @FrankEpps: Go find a dictionary and look up the word "mocking" and then come back and point out where I did what the dictionary says. Using emotive terms like that doesn't help your case at all. Believe it or not, I was trying to help you and if you had followed my advice, it would have helped you far more than you realise. You're like the karate kid who just wants to learn how to do karate chops and can't believe he has to waste his time washing Mr Miyagi's car. All I can say is, "Wax on; wax off!" (That's a terrible movie to take a metaphor from, but if the shoe fits…)

Comment: now ur becoming unreasonable. i'm very disappointed that u came acros this question cause ur ruining my evening, if jerry posted his answer first i'd completely understand it but u show up and offer some shit. good day to u sir

Comment: @FrankEpps: Fine. But let's get a couple of things straight: 1) I genuinely tried to help you in the way that I thought would yield the greatest benefit to you; 2) calling such efforts “shit” is the most offensive thing anyone has said in this discussion so far.

Comment: sir i'm sorry i didn't mean to hurt ur feelings. instead of "shit" i meant elitist, superficial, and arrogant.

Comment: @FrankEpps: If you thought that that would hurt my feelings, then you haven't been paying attention. I have much too thick a skin for that. Your unabated descent into slanderous vitriol strongly suggests that you still don't.

Comment: lol u dont even know what "slanderous" means i suggest u invest in a dictionary to clear up ur blatant confusion... u cant redefine the english language as u go

Comment: @FrankEpps: "A false and malicious statement or report about someone." Let's tackle the "false" element first. You made three accusations: elitism, superficiality and arrogance. Elitism is easy to dispel, at least in my own mind, because I've never had any sense that I'm better than you. I know that we're all (myself included) born ignorant about everything and rely on others who've gone before us to show the way. I only saw (and still see) you as going through the same learning process that I had to go through many years ago, and I wanted to help you in the most effective way I can.

Comment: I suppose I failed in that goal, but "elitism" goes to intent, not outcomes. Somehow, you've translated the simple fact that I know more than you about some aspects of programming into "elitism", but nothing could be further from the truth. Similar arguments apply to "arrogant" and I frankly don't know what you mean by "superficial". The "malicious" bit is easy. Your statement was clearly intended to insult and demean. That seems to fit the "malicious" bill to me.